# SVN why can't I add files that begin with a period

Tags: svn

I am using subversion for a project that contains filenames that begin with a period.  This is what happens when I try to add/delete these files to the repository.

```
$ svn delete CRM/Core/DAO/.listAll.php
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'CRM/Core/DAO/.listAll.php' is not under version control

$ svn add CRM/Core/DAO/.listAll.php
svn: warning: 'CRM/Core/DAO/.listAll.php' is already under version control
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is strange, subversion does support file names starting with a period. I use it myself in my projects. Unless this isn't a bug in your specific svn version there must be some problem in your setup.

Comment: What's output of `svn propget svn:ignore` on that directory?

Comment: @raina77ow I don't get any output from that.

Comment: can you run a "svn status CRM/Core/DAO/" ?

Comment: @Peter Parker svn status CRM/Core/DAO/ shows a question mark to the left of each file.
?       .listAll.php
?       .permissions.php